# Constructor Function in Mocha not recognised

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm completely out of ideas as to what is going on here so hopefully someone can help.

Here is my script that I'm testing;

```
function MyFunc() {

    this.test = 'hello world';

};

module.exports = MyFunc;
```

Here is my test;

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var MyFunc = require('../myfunc.js');

describe('MyFunc', function() {

    it('test should equal to Hello World', function() {
        var subject = new MyFunc;
        expect(subject.test).to.eql('hello world');
    });

})
```

When I run the test it fails and it gives me this message;

```
TypeError: MyFunc is not a function
```

I've simplified the code just to get my problem across, but I've tried several variations to no avail. I've spent quite a bit of time looking for similar issues with no joy (usually that means it's something stupid I'm doing. Lets hope).

I test my Angular code in a very similar way with no issues at all. I'm stumped!

Thanks for taking the time to read,

Anthony

Answer (score 1):

Change `var subject = new MyFunc` ===> `var subject = new MyFunc()`

```js
describe('MyFunc', function() {

    it('test should equal to Hello World', function() {
        var subject = new MyFunc();
        expect(subject.test).to.eql('hello world');
    });

})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had already tried this but it returns the same error :(

Comment: directory where `myfunc.js` ?

Comment: It's pointing to the right file, but when I console.log MyFunc it's just an empty object {}.

Comment: I was being stupid. The path had to go back another ../../ but because I named my test file the same as my script I was actually testing my test. Wow.

Thanks so much for taking the time to help out. Much appreciated.